# Пропал выбор папки для установки при установке VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, установка

столкнулся со странной проблемой - при установке VS Code не появляется пункт выбора папки для установки, и установщик пытается установить всё на изъятый из компьютера жесткий диск и выдаёт ошибку. Есть идеи как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Через Программы и компоненты удалил остатки старого VS Code и поле выбора установки появилось